# Implement document processing system

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have to implement a class with method that takes document:

> ```
> struct TDocument {
>     string url; // document identifier
>     uint64_t pubDate;
>     uint64_t fetchTime;
>     string text;
>     uint64_t firstFetchTime = 0; 
> };
> ```
>
> The method should return document with updated fields according to the following rules:
>
> 1. `text` and `fetchTime` must be the same as the document with max `fetchTime` (take into account only documents with the same URL)
> 2. `pubDate` must be the same as the `pubDate` in document with min `fetchTime` (take into account only documents with the same URL)
> 3. `firstFetchTime` must be the same as the `fetchTime` in the document with min `fetchTime` (take into account only documents with the same URL)
>
> Example:
> Input:
> url="url1", pubDate=1, fetchTime=1, text="text1"
> url="url1", pubDate=2, fetchTime=3, text="text2"
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> url="url1", pubDate=1, fetchTime=1, text="text1", firstFetchTime=1 // for the first input line return the same document with updated  firstFetchTime
>
> url="url1", pubDate=1, fetchTime=2, text="text2", firstFetchTime=1 // for the second input line update pubDate is 1 (because the should take min value among documents with the same URL
> ```

My idea: is to store minFetchTime and maxFetchTime among documents  with the same URL

Could you please review my solution?
Are there similar tasks on the LeetCode.com?
Code

```
struct TDocument {
    string url;
    uint64_t pubDate; // pubdate of the minFetchTime 
    uint64_t fetchTime; // maxFetchTime
    string text; // maxFetchTime
    uint64_t firstFetchTime = 0; // minFetchTime
};


struct UtilityDocument {
    UtilityDocument(string url_, uint64_t pubDate_, string text_, uint64_t firstFetchTime_, uint64_t maxFetchTime_, uint64_t minFetchTime_)
        : url(url_), pubDate(pubDate_), text(text_), firstFetchTime(firstFetchTime_), maxFetchTime(maxFetchTime_), minFetchTime(minFetchTime_) {}
public:
    string url;
    uint64_t pubDate;
    string text;
    uint64_t firstFetchTime;

    uint64_t maxFetchTime;
    uint64_t minFetchTime;

};


class TProcessor {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<TDocument> Process(std::shared_ptr<TDocument> input) {
        if (docs_.contains(input->url)) {
            if (input->fetchTime > docs_[input->url]->maxFetchTime) {
                docs_[input->url]->maxFetchTime = input->fetchTime;
                docs_[input->url]->text = input->text;

                input->pubDate =  docs_[input->url]->pubDate;
                input->firstFetchTime = docs_[input->url]->minFetchTime;
            } 
            if (input->fetchTime < docs_[input->url]->minFetchTime) {
                docs_[input->url]->minFetchTime = input->fetchTime;
                docs_[input->url]->pubDate = input->pubDate;

                input->text = docs_[input->url]->text;
                input->fetchTime = docs_[input->url]->maxFetchTime;
            }
        } else {
            input->firstFetchTime = input->fetchTime;
            docs_[input->url] = shared_ptr<UtilityDocument>(new UtilityDocument(
                input->url,
                input->pubDate,
                input->text,
                input->firstFetchTime,
                input->fetchTime, // maxFetchTime
                input->fetchTime // minFetchTime
            ));
        }
        return input;
    };
private:
   unordered_map<string, std::shared_ptr<UtilityDocument>> docs_;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be some documentation, I think at least of `TDocument` and `TProcessor.Process()`.

It looks tempting to have something modelling what's common to `TDocument` and whatever models *info about all same URL `TDocument`s for `Process()`* - I don't think the latter is a/one *document* and name it differently.
Without any methods in `TDocument`, the question of *is-a* seems moot,
but seeing no use of `UtilityDocument.firstFetchTime`, I'm unconvinced derivation helps.

Far as I remember, specifying visibility `public` is pointless in a `struct` without preceding restriction.

In `Process()`, all those repetitions of `docs_[input->url]` are too verbose for my taste.

As [37307554 points out](/a/289128/93149), not setting the doc's `pubDate` and `firstFetchTime` looks flaky, I'll extend that to `text` and `fetchTime`.

```
/*** a TDocument keeps URL, text, publication date and time fetched
 *   and in addition the time this URL was first fetched _when Process()ed_ */
struct TDocument {
    string url;                  // document identifier
    uint64_t pubDate;            // processed: of doc with min fetchTime
    uint64_t fetchTime;          // processed: of doc with max fetchTime
    string text;                 // processed: of doc with max fetchTime
    uint64_t firstFetchTime = 0; // processed: of doc with min fetchTime
};


struct URLInfo {  // for documents with same URL
    URLInfo(string url_, string text_,
            uint64_t pubDate_, uint64_t maxFetchTime_, uint64_t minFetchTime_)
        : url(url_), text(text_),
          pubDate(pubDate_), maxFetchTime(maxFetchTime_), minFetchTime(minFetchTime_)
        {}
    string url;
    string text;
    uint64_t pubDate;
    uint64_t maxFetchTime;
    uint64_t minFetchTime;
};


class TProcessor {
public:
    /** URL info instantiated or updated as necessary;
     *  text and fetchTime are set to the URL's text & max fetchTime;
     *  pubDate & firstFetchTime to the URL's pubDate & min fetchTime. */
    std::shared_ptr<TDocument> Process(std::shared_ptr<TDocument> input) {
        auto found = docs_.find(input->url);
        if (found != docs_.end()) {
            // assert(found->minFetchTime <= found->maxFetchTime) ?
            if (input->fetchTime > found->maxFetchTime) {
                found->maxFetchTime = input->fetchTime;
                found->text = input->text;
            } else if (input->fetchTime < found->minFetchTime) {
                found->minFetchTime = input->fetchTime;
                found->pubDate = input->pubDate;
            } // XXX what if ==?
            input->pubDate        = found->pubDate;
            input->fetchTime      = found->maxFetchTime;
            input->text           = found->text;
            input->firstFetchTime = found->minFetchTime;
        } else {
            input->firstFetchTime = input->fetchTime;
            docs_[input->url] = shared_ptr<URLInfo>(new URLInfo(
                    input->url,
                    input->text,
                    input->pubDate,
                    input->fetchTime, // maxFetchTime
                    input->fetchTime  // minFetchTime
                ));
        }
        return input;
    };
private:
   unordered_map<string, std::shared_ptr<URLInfo>> docs_;
};
```

Using an `else if` where comparing doc `fetchTime` and URL `max/minFetchTime` leads me to suspect a gap in the specification.

Caveat: I didn't code C++ in earnest for decades, no modern C++, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

When a new document with the same URL but a different `fetchTime` is processed in your `process` method, you correctly update `maxFetchTime` and `minFetchTime` as needed. However, the logic to update `pubDate` and `firstFetchTime` in the input document could be more explicitly aligned with the rules. Specifically, `pubDate` should always reflect the `pubDate` of the document with the minimum `fetchTime`, and `firstFetchTime` should also be updated to reflect the minimum fetchTime.

You can optimize updating the `input` document with values from `docs_` and vice versa by determining whether an update is necessary before making any changes. You can do this by first checking if the current document's `fetchTime` is indeed the new minimum or maximum for that URL before proceeding with updates.

Consider breaking down the `Process` method into smaller helper functions for handling specific tasks, such as updating the document for a new maximum `fetchTime` or a new minimum `fetchTime`.

If and when `TProcessor::Process` might be called from multiple threads, consider thread safety for your `docs_` map as the current implementation does not appear to be thread-safe.

Consider adding error handling or validation for the input document, such as checking for null pointers or invalid data.